# TypeError: d.ListingCreationDate.getUTCFullYear is not a constructor

Tags: parsing, datetime, d3.js, filter

I'm trying to filter my data by year, but don't know where/how to parse out my year from my dataset (loaded from csv). (both draw(d) and plot_loans(d) functions are called). 
I get the error: TypeError: d.ListingCreationDate.getUTCFullYear is not a constructor.

```
function draw(d) {
function plot_loans(d){
function update(year){
              var filtered = d.filter(function(d){
                  return new d.ListingCreationDate.getUTCFullYear() === year;
                  });
}
}
```

This is my loading function:

```
d3.csv("loandata_sample.csv", function(d) {
  return {
    ListingKey: d.ListingKey,
    ListingCreationDate: Date(d.ListingCreationDate)
  };
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This part of your code is giving you that error:

`return new d.ListingCreationDate.getUTCFullYear() === year;`

the `new` keyword attempts to make a new object from a constructor, which you aren't providing. Depending on how you want to store the date, you should either change it to:

`return (new Date(d.ListingCreationDate)).getUTCFullYear() === year;`

(if d.ListingCreationDate) is a string

or:
`return d.ListingCreationDate.getUTCFullYear() === year;`

(if d.ListingCreationDate) is a Date object. In this case you have to initialize the date object, changing `ListingCreationDate: Date(d.ListingCreationDate)` to `ListingCreationDate: new Date(d.ListingCreationDate)`

Comment: When I tried ListingCreationDate: new Date(d.ListingCreationDate) i got an invalid date returned

Comment: when i implemented your first suggestion, (return (new Date(d.ListingCreationDate)).getUTCFullYear() === year;) and called update(2010); in the console window, i get an error stating that update is not defined.